# How can I prevent applications from stopping when Ubuntu is locked?

Tags: screen

I am new to Ubuntu, and I need a little bit of help. When I am not using the computer, my screen is getting locked down and with that the running applications are stopping. (like: Spotify,BitTorrent and such). Please help me

Comment: By 'locked down' do you mean your computer is going into low power standby or hibernation?  The screen just 'turning off' and the session auto-locking doesn't affect background apps like the ones you listed.

Comment: No I mean, I do not use the computer for a while, and it's getting locked down. After it gets locked down the applications are stopping. I was listening music on Spotify, and suddenly it stopped playing, I came to see what was going on, and saw that the Ubuntu has locked down the screen. I do not why it is like that, but it is happening with BitTorrent too. Thank You for your reply

Comment: what do you mean by ***locked down***?  It's unclear what you're asking about.  The "lock screen" ***does not*** affect those applications - I'm speaking from experience as I use bittorrent for ubuntu ISOs and other legal uses and don't see that behavior.

Comment: @Dániel Illés are you sure your operating system and computer continue working i this 'locked down' time?

Comment: @S_Flash I think yes, the computer is on, it is just giving me the login screen. On the upper right corner I can see that the computer is connected to the wifi. Although when I check the statistics on the BitTorrent I can see that it was not seeding at time when the computer was locked down(login screen). I am sorry, I can only tell you what I am experiencing.